# Google similar images algorithm

Tags: algorithm, image-processing

Does any one have an idea regarding what sort of algorithm might Google be using to find similar images ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23931/what-algorithm-to-compare-two-images/3445087#3445087

Answer (score 4):

No, but they *could* be using [SIFT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale-invariant_feature_transform).

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure this has much to do with image processing. When I ask for "similar images" of the Eiffel tower, I get a bunch of photos of Paris Hilton, and street maps from Paris. Curiously, all of these images have the word "Paris" in the file name.

Answer (score 1):

Currently the Google Image Search provides these filtering options:

- Image size
- Face detection
- Continuous-tone ("Photo") vs. Smooth shading ("Clipart") vs. bitonal("Line drawing")
- Color histogram

These options can be seen in its Image Search Result page.

Comment: No i talking about similar images. http://similar-images.googlelabs.com/

Comment: I tried that tool and it didn't seem interesting at all. At best they're simply doing clustering using both word-image information (for example, linking the word "Paris" with all images appearing on web pages that include the word "Paris") and the image information (image size, face, histogram etc)

Comment: They may also take clues from http://images.google.com/imagelabeler/

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about faces, but see at least:

- http://www.incm.cnrs-mrs.fr/LaurentPerrinet/Publications/Perrinet08spie
- [Compare two images the python/linux way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1927660/compare-two-images-the-python-linux-way)

I have heard, that one should use this when comparing images
(I mean: make the prob model, calc. the probs, use this):

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence

Or then it might even be one of those PCFG things that MIT people tend to use with robotics stuff. One I read used some sort of PCFG model made of basic shapes (that you can rotate magically) and searched the best match with

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inside-outside_algorithm