# Algorithm to filter out photographs out of a bunch of random images

Tags: image, algorithm, artificial-intelligence, image-recognition

i need a way to determine wheter a picture is a photograph or not. I've got a bunch of random image files (paper document scans, logos and of course photographs taken by a camera) and i need to filter out only the photographs for creating a preview.

The solution proposed at [Determine if image is photograph or drawing, quickly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13119796/determine-if-image-is-photograph-or-drawing-quickly) only works in a limited way (i.e. some logos are completly black with wite font, some logos have only colors in it - no white areas) and sometimes i've got scan of a white paper containing multiple photographs with white space arround - i need to identify those, too - because then i have to key out the white part and save the photographs on the scan in seperate files.

Comment: This is something that will be difficult with programming.

Comment: what is the difference between a photograph of a paper document and a paper document scan?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your process to do this should probably be similar to the following:

1. Extract features from the image (pixel values, groups of pixels,
   HoG, SIFT, GIST, DCT, Wavelet, Dictionary learning coefficients,
   etc. depending on how much time you have)
2. Aggregate these features somehow so that you get a fixed length
   vector (histogram, pyramid scheme)
3. Apply a standard classification (SVM, k-NN, neural network, Random
   Forest) or clustering algorithm (k-means, GMM, etc.) and measure how
   well it works (F1 score is usually okay, ROC may be better for
   2-class problems)
4. Repeat from step 1 with different features if you are unsatisfied with the results from 3

The solution you reference seems to be pretty reasonable in terms of steps 1 and 2.

A simple next step in extracting and aggregating features could be to create histograms from all pixel values in the image. If you have a lot of labeled data you should feed these features to a standard classifier. Otherwise, run a clustering algorithm on these histogram features and check the cluster assignments to see if they are correlated with the photograph/non-photograph assignment.

Answer (score 0):

Check the following paper: 
http://www.vision.ee.ethz.ch/~gallju/projects/houghforest/houghforest.html . They provide source code.

I believe the program  accepts an input file with negative and positive images for training. The output of the classification part of it will be a image voting map (hough map?). You might need to decide on a threshold value to locate regions of interest. So if there two logos in the image it will mark out both of them. The algorithm worked very well for me in a past.

Training on 100 positive and 100 negative images should be enough, I believe. Don't use big images for training also (256x256 should be enough).