# Understanding histogram() in Pillow

Tags: python, histogram, python-imaging-library

From the docs:

> im.histogram() => list
>
> Returns a histogram for the image. The histogram is returned as a list
>   of pixel counts, one for each pixel value in the source image. If the
>   image has more than one band, the histograms for all bands are
>   concatenated (for example, the histogram for an “RGB” image contains
>   768 values).

I understand that there are 256 values for Red, 256 for Green and 256 for Blue (256 * 3 = 768).

```
for i, value in enumerate(im.histogram()):
    print i, value
```

Produces:

```
0 329
1 145
... (skipping some)
256 460
... (skipping some)
767 3953
```

**My question is:** does that mean that there were:
329 pixels that had a value of `R = 0, G = 0, B = 0` and 
145 pixels that had a value of `R = 1, G = 0, B = 0` and 
460 pixels that had a value of `R = 256, G = 1, B = 0` and 
3953 pixels that had a value of `R = 256, G = 256, B = 256` etc. ?

Is that how I should read the output?

Comment: Given that the documentation says jack about the order, I'd generate 3 separate pics of the primary colors and see what the histogram function outputs.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds like a good idea. Would still be interesting to see what the order means though.

Comment: I'm sure if you wanted to work through the source code you could establish the actual order, but sometimes the simplest methods are the  best.  BWT when you do figure it out, post your answer back here.

Comment: @PeterM: Looks like the data is for each channel, see voithos' answer below.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I haven't tested, but from the documentation, the wording seems to indicate that the histogram only applies to each channel (e.g. Red, Green, Blue) **individually**.

> If the image has more than one band, the histograms for all bands are
>   **concatenated** (for example, the histogram for an “RGB” image contains
>   768 values).

So, no, the examples you gave aren't really correct. `768` values is just `256 * 3`, which is the number of possible red values, plus the number of possible green values, plus the number of possible blue values *independently*. It *does not* represent all possible combinations of red, green, and blue, which would instead be `256 ^ 3 == 16777216`.

From what I can see, the interpretation of your example histogram values should be:

```
329  pixels with value of R = 0, G = ?, B = ? and
145  pixels with value of R = 1, G = ?, B = ? and
...
460  pixels with value of R = ?, G = 1, B = ? and
...
3953 pixels with value of R = ?, G = ?, B = 256
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a really clear answer. I'll look at each color separately.

Answer (score 3):

No, you don't know how many pixels had (e.g.) R=0, G=0, B=0.
That would require a histogram with something like 16 million entries.

You only know how many had R=0, how many had G=0, and how many had B=0, taken independently.

It would be entirely possible for the R=0 pixels to have a great many different amounts of G and B.

Comment: Thanks, major math fail on my part. `256 ^ 3` != `256 * 3`

Answer (score -1):

if the mode is RGB to open a image, 768 mean is Red grey list[0-255 pixs nums]+Green grey list[0-255 pix nums]+ Blue grey list[0-255 pix numbs]

im is a Image object by RGB

In [59]: x = reduce(lambda x,y:x+y,im.histogram())

In [60]: x
Out[60]: 47191725

In [61]: im.size
Out[61]: (4731, 3325)

In [62]: 4731*3325
Out[62]: 15730575

In [63]: 4731*3325*3
Out[63]: 47191725

In [64]:

or other way:

r, g, b = im.split()

len(r.histogram()) = 256

len(g.histogram()) = 256

len(b.histogram()) = 256

Comment: I'm not sure about the meaning of this answer. What is the objective?