# Webdriver - save_screenshot - bit-depth

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, png

I have a MIPS based device, which runs Blink based browser. (With Webdriver/Selenium).

I wanted to automate few test cases and hence used Selenium. Instead of Visual comparison of few things, wanted to compare the images using Python PIL.

- First to got the "preferred output", by running it on PC-chrome and got the Screen shot of the element [See the Link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422262/take-a-screenshot-with-selenium-webdriver)
- Similarly run the test on device.
- Compare the two image using - [See the Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1927660/compare-two-images-the-python-linux-way)

But it gives me error: "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'NoneType'"

When I checked the images, the images saved are in two different "Bit-depth". the Image stored from PC was 24bits and from device was 32bit.

How can I configure webdriver to capture image in different bit depths?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main difference is "Alpha" channel. 
Instead of setting webdriver, I have modified my test itself, to always convert the image to "RGB" format ([Link](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/image-sig/2007-February/004302.html)) and then compare.
In this way, I am able to overcome the issue. In case some body has an idea on disabling "Alpha" channel in WebDriver itself, it would be better.