# Comparing two images/pictures, and mark the difference

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am learning to compare two images/pictures. I found the post [Compare two images the python/linux way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1927660/compare-two-images-the-python-linux-way) is very useful and I have some questions regarding the technique.

Question 1:

The post shows ways to compare 2 pictures/images. Probably the easiest way is:

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageChops

im1 = Image.open("file1.jpg")
im2 = Image.open("file2.jpg")

diff = ImageChops.difference(im2, im1).getbbox()

print diff
```

when I have 2 look alike pictures and run above, it give result:

```
(389, 415, 394, 420)
```

It’s the position on the picture where the difference in 2 pictures lies. So my question is, would it be possible to mark the difference on the picture (for example, draw a circle)?

Question 2:

```
import math, operator
from PIL import Image
def compare(file1, file2):
    image1 = Image.open(file1)
    image2 = Image.open(file2)
    h1 = Image.open("image1").histogram()
    h2 = Image.open("image2").histogram()

    rms = math.sqrt(reduce(operator.add, map(lambda a,b: (a-b)**2, h1, h2))/len(h1))

if __name__=='__main__':
    import sys
    file1 = ('c:\\a.jpg')        # added line
    file2 = ('c:\\b.jpg')        # added line

    file1, file2 = sys.argv[1:]
    print compare(file1, file2)
```

When I run above, it gives an error “ValueError: need more than 0 values to unpack”, and the problem lies in this line:

```
file1, file2 = sys.argv[1:]
```

How can I have it corrected? and I tried below it neither works.

```
    print compare('c:\\a.jpg', 'c:\\b.jpg')
```

### Update

Added question following Matt's help.

It can draw a rectangle to mark the difference on the two images/pictures. When the two images/pictures looked general the same but there are small spots differences spread. It draws a big rectangle marking the big area include all the spots differences. Is there a way to identically mark the differences individually?

Comment: Please don't use your title to tag your question.

Comment: thanks, Burhan Khalid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Regarding your first question:**

```
import ImageDraw
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im2)
draw.rectangle(diff)
im2.show()
```

**Regarding your second question:**

The error states, that `sys.argv` does not contain enough values to be assigned to `file1` and `file2`. You need to pass the names of the two files you want to compare to you python script (the variable `sys.arv` contains the name of your script and all the command line parameters):

```
python name_of_your_script.py file1.jpg file2.jpg
```

Answer (score 1):

Question 1: [ImageDraw](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/imagedraw.htm)

```
image = Image.open("x.png")
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
draw.ellipse((x-r, y-r, x+r, y+r))
```

Comment: thanks, eivl. your help is appreciated. however another users provides more details. so hope you don't mind I am choosing that.

Comment: There is no problem, we both used the ImageDraw class and the draw method, and you should do so as well! =)