# Use imagequick to compare images

Tags: image

I don't understand how the `compare` script of imagequick work.

I compare an image to the same image (a copy) [image: Image to compare]

I do

`compare -metric  A.png B.png C.png`

`B.png` is exactly the same image as `A.png` (I did a copy)

Here is the result.

I was thinking that `C.png` will be fully white, but that is not.

[image: Result of the comparaison]

I would like to know if two image are stricly identic. Is it possible to get an ouput which will tell me "yes, the two images are identic" or "no, the two images are note identic".

Comment: Imagequick? So is a single red pixel (rgb 255,0,0) saved as a GIF identical to a single red pixel in a PNG? Is a single red pixel in a PNG identical to a single red pixel in a PNG made 1 second later but where the files have different checksums because the date inside is different? It depends how you define *"identical"*.

Comment: that mean all pixel are identical. "compare" of imagequick is able to compare not checksum, but the pixels.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1927660/compare-two-images-the-python-linux-way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some examples to help you understand how image comparison works.

The `-metric AE` tells you the *Absolute Error*, which is the number of pixels that differ - so it will be zero if all pixels are identical.

**1. Compare two images that are *exact* copies of each other in *every* respect**

```
convert -size 128x128 xc:red red.png                    # Make red image
cp red.png perfectCopy.png                              # Make perfect copy
compare -metric AE red.png perfectCopy.png result.png   # Count differing pixels
0                                                       # There are none - identical
```

According to standard Unix tools (`md5`, `diff`, `tmp`), files are binary identical and md5 checksums identical:

```
md5 red.png perfectCopy.png 
MD5 (red.png) = 39236e0e0dfb70da0e9bcbfbcf7b8181
MD5 (perfectCopy.png) = 39236e0e0dfb70da0e9bcbfbcf7b8181
```

**ImageMagick** hashes over pixels only (not including metadata) are identical:

```
identify -format "%#:%f\n" red.gif perfectCopy.png 
1157038985fec4573888bc7e74a5a728e3aa5cbc49e18253c934295162a9aeea:red.gif
1157038985fec4573888bc7e74a5a728e3aa5cbc49e18253c934295162a9aeea:perfectCopy.png
```

**2. Compare two images with identical appearance but different metadata**

```
convert -size 128x128 xc:red red.png                    # Make red image
sleep 2
convert -size 128x128 xc:red redDifferentDate.png       # Make red image with different date
compare -metric AE red.png redDifferentDate.png result.png
0                                                       # No difference
```

But, according to standard Unix tools (`diff`,`md5`,`sum`), the files are different - because the date is in there.

```
md5 red.png redDifferentDate.png 
MD5 (red.png) = 004088f6d275f431cedb74bc0209bbc5
MD5 (redDifferentDate.png) = d7d36f56e1940251f9804bd795ef4157
```

But **ImageMagick** knows images better, and its calculated hashes (checksum) over pixel data only (not including metadata) are the same:

```
identify -format "%#:%f\n" red.gif redDifferentDate.png 
1157038985fec4573888bc7e74a5a728e3aa5cbc49e18253c934295162a9aeea:red.gif
1157038985fec4573888bc7e74a5a728e3aa5cbc49e18253c934295162a9aeea:redDifferentDate.png
```

**3. Compare two images with identical pixels, but totally different sizes and formats**

```
convert -size 128x128 xc:red red.png                    # Make red PNG
convert -size 128x128 xc:red red.gif                    # Make red  GIF
compare -metric AE red.png red.gif result.png           # Count differing pixels
0                                                       # No difference
```

But, files and md5 hashes differ:

```
diff red.png red.gif
Binary files red.png and red.gif differ

md5 red.png red.gif 
MD5 (red.png) = aed0840c2c99425c25bd782e7b409022
MD5 (red.gif) = 5869df00d7b3cab3495a6c402ba61ec9
```

Again, **ImageMagick** knows better and the hashes over pixel data only (not including metadata) are still the same:

```
identify -format "%#:%f\n" red.gif red.png 
1157038985fec4573888bc7e74a5a728e3aa5cbc49e18253c934295162a9aeea:red.gif
1157038985fec4573888bc7e74a5a728e3aa5cbc49e18253c934295162a9aeea:red.png
```

**4. Compare two grossly different files**

Obviously if we create two grossly different files each full of random noise, everyone agrees they are different:

```
convert -size 128x128 xc:gray +noise random random1.png   # Make random image
convert -size 128x128 xc:gray +noise random random2.png   # Make random image
compare -metric AE random[12].png result.png              # Count differing pixels
16384                                                     # Yep, a fair few differ!
```

---

There are other metrics available, such as *MeanSquared*, *RootMeanSquared* etc - you can list them using:

```
identify -list metric
```

**Output**

```
AE
Fuzz
MAE
MEPP
MSE
NCC
PAE
PHASH
PSNR
RMSE
```

Comment: Many think Marks. -metric AE is what I need