# Difference between adb screenshot and image taken from bitmap of view

Tags: android, imagemagick, adb, screenshot, android-espresso

I have two Screenshots
First one is taken using adb command "adb shell screencap"
Second one is created from view bitmap

When i compare both the screenshots using third party tools like imagemagic it is showing as different images

How do i match both ?

Note: both the screenshots are looking same (with human eye)
No idea why there is a difference when compare tools are used
Both the images are of same width height

Images are uploaded in following link

https://wetransfer.com/downloads/2535f3a8751d01eeafec7994e020dd9a20190219123408/2203ce

Comment: probably the capture format/quality is different. What is the file type of images?

Comment: Have a read here https://stackoverflow.com/a/43799726/2836621

Comment: If your screen capture creates a JPG format file, then it will have lossy compression and that will cause a difference. Are the image dimensions the same?

Comment: @fmw42 yes the dimesions are same
I tried removing alpha and comapred with view screenshot but it is showing difference
thanks for your answer

Comment: Is there alpha from a screen snap? Can you post a zip file containing both images, so they do not get changed by this forum's upload process?

Comment: @fmw42 I have upload both the images
one from adb one from view

https://wetransfer.com/downloads/2535f3a8751d01eeafec7994e020dd9a20190219123408/2203ce

Comment: @MarkSetchell  can you please help me how to do it
I have uploaded images in wetransfer and shared link
https://wetransfer.com/downloads/2535f3a8751d01eeafec7994e020dd9a20190219123408/2203ce

In my case both the images are of same size and identical looking 
but different pixel information

Comment: When i checked RGB values in http://csfieldguide.org.nz/en/interactives/pixel-viewer/index.html

for one of the pixel RGB values are 141 173 76 
for other image for the same pixel position 145 179 76

Comment: I see that fuzz can be used for RGB differences 
but I am still seeing differences in images

Comment: The ADB image has an alpha/transparency channel which the Espresso one lacks.

Comment: The alpha channel on the one is totally opaque and can be removed with no change in color. The two images are different. One has more content at the top and bottom than the other. Just a guess, one has been processed with a profile and then the profile may have been stripped. Otherwise, I cannot say for sure. One generates a histogram from identify -verbose and so has limited number of colors (958). The other does not generate a histogram and so must have many more colors. Possible it has had some antialiasing include. Or the other one was 8-bit color convert to 24-bit color.