# Detecting 3D Image Formats in Python

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, opencv3.0

3D videos are usually saved either as Side-By-Side images, or Over-Under images.

For example:
SBS
[image: A side-by-side stereo image]
OU
[image: An over-under stereo image]

My TV can automatically detect when 3D content is being played - even when there's no specific file metadata. It does this by analysing the images and recognising their stereo nature.

I'm aware of how to calculate a disparity map once I have a stereo pair - but how do I detect whether the image is HSBS or OU?

One tactic would be to separate the image into top/bottom and left/right - then compute the differences between the pairs. Whichever is shorter, wins.

I could use [Mean Squared Error or Structural Similarity Measure](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/09/15/python-compare-two-images/)

Or I could [compare the histograms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1927660/compare-two-images-the-python-linux-way)

But these feel a bit hacky and they only give me an approximation of whether two sides are similar.

Is there any way to detect the vertical or horizontal split?

Comment: No metadata present at all? Then the image contents is all you got, and all you *can* use.

Comment: Yup! In this case, I'm just taking screenshots from existing movies.