# How to break "select different image" CAPTCHA with Python

Tags: python, authentication, captcha

So I have this code in Python3 that scraps data from websites through object recongnition (I used this to automate the download process inside a flash player based website) and Selenium. The problem is that I'm stuck with this website that have a custom made Captcha where the user have to select the different image from the group and I don´t know how to download or get these images from the site in order to identify the different one, has anyone solved a problem like this? or have an idea on how to solve this captcha with any other technique or method?

[This is the login that has the CAPTCHA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VHqbv.png)

And here's the link to the site which is in spanish. The captcha basically says "Select the different image"
https://portalempresas.sb.cl/login.php

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To download those images as png files you could do:

```py
from io import BytesIO
from PIL import Image

# Download image function
def downloadImage(element,imgName):
    img = element.screenshot_as_png
    stream = BytesIO(img)
    image = Image.open(stream).convert("RGB")
    image.save(imgName)

# Find all the web elements of the captcha images    
image_elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("*//div[contains(@class,'captcha-image')]")

# Output name for the images
image_base_name = "Imagen_[idx].png"

# Download each image
for i in range(len(image_elements)):
    downloadImage(image_elements[i],image_base_name.replace("[idx]","%s"%i))
```

**Edit 1:**

If you want to compare 2 images to see if they are equal you could try with this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1927660/compare-two-images-the-python-linux-way)

**Edit 2:**

Using the solution edited above, these are the results:

[image: captcha1]
[image: captcha1]
[image: captcha1]
[image: captcha1]
[image: captha2]

Comment: It totally worked, thanks a lot bro! Saludos desde Chile carnal!!

Comment: I am glad that it helped! Saludos carnalito!

Comment: the solution failed! :( when it tries to get all of the image elements through the xpath, it doesn't get them all, downloading almost a random one, please help :(

Comment: I'll take a look and let you know how does it goes. how many images does the program dowloads?

Comment: If I leave it like this "...div[2]/div[*]" none :(

Comment: I edited the code as it has some errors. Please let me know if that helps! :D

Comment: Omg bro you are a beast! the code works! thank you so much! I'll let you know if I have any problems. Muchísimas gracias carnal!