# Picture matching from webcam pictures with picture noise problem

Tags: c#

Hy

I take two pictures from a webcam and split them into a 9 pieces. Then i match the pieces of the two pictures. The problem is that my webcam have a picture noise. So my programm thinks that in every piece of the second picture have chanced something.
I need a logical push to solve my problem please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pictures from the web cam will never *exactly* match - even the slightest change in lighting will cause a difference. For this kind of picture matching you have to use a forgiving algorithm that allows at least some change and still makes a match. Create a histogram of each image, then calculating the difference seems to be a promising approach.

See the following threads on SO (just for examples, there are many more threads):

1. [Image comparison - fast algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/843972/image-comparison-fast-algorithm)
2. [Image comparison algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1819124/image-comparison-algorithm)

Also I would check out [Emgu](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) if you are working with .NET, this is a .NET wrapper for [openCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/), a computer vision library.

Comment: who to match images with emgu?