# How to use a low-resolution, cropped photo as a guide to re-crop a higher resolution copy of the original?

Tags: image, node.js, image-processing, imagemagick

I have a square, low-resolution photo, which has been cropped (by the user) out of a high-resolution, non-square, original.  The low-res photo has then been resized downwards into a thumbnail.  I'd like to automatically (no user-intervention required) re-crop the original photo in the same way to achieve a higher-resolution copy of the square version.  I **do not** have access to the original cropper coordinates.  All I have are these two photos.

Here are some example images (from my Facebook profile) to illustrate what I mean:

[Original, high-resolution photo](https://sphotos-b.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-prn1/58640_601472936324_6399908_n.jpg) - [Cropped, then shrunk, square photo](http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-snc4/41653_7304838_9249_q.jpg)

Again, the goal is to use the small photo as a guide to get a much higher resolution square photo from the source.

The only constraints on the solution are:

1. Generality: I'm using this for profile pictures, so if it only works on faces that is perfectly acceptable!  No need to generalize to all sorts of random images, pictures of people is a great place to start.
2. Platform: I'm using Node, but I'd be happy to run this process in Ruby, Python, Java, or C++ (with Node bindings).  It would almost certainly run on Heroku or AWS.
3. Speed: It's going to need to be pretty speedy.  For this to be useful, it would have to run in an on-line fashion, since I'd be blocking the user's interface waiting for this action.

Does anyone have any ideas? I don't know a lot about image processing, so I wouldn't really know where to start.

EDIT:  For Facebook, specifically, there is a solution that is not nearly so hard.  The original crop data is available for profile images: https://graph.facebook.com/bcherry/profile?fields=pic_crop

This is going to get me over my immediate hurdle, but may not be a long-term solution, so the answers provided below are still quite helpful to the more general problem.

Comment: Do you know the dimensions of the un-cropped low-resolution photo?

Comment: I'm not precisely sure what you're asking, but I do not have any information other than the two images.

Comment: I presume you don't know what the resizing ratio is for the thumbnail? If not this becomes a pretty hard problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I will not comment to Javascript-ness of my solution - you're basically trying to perform [Image Registration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_registration) between the original and cropped, resized image.

There are [many](http://library.utia.cas.cz/prace/20030125.pdf) different methods to do something like this - for your particular purpose, I would start with a [Phase-Correlation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_correlation) like approach.

EDIT: I just found a nice script using ImageMagick that does exactly what you need. [NormCrossCorr](http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/normcrosscorr/index.php) "computes the normalized cross correlation surface to find where a small image best matches within a larger image."

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes, that certainly sounds the correct thing.  Thanks for the answer!

Comment: That won't work. It would only work if the thumbnail was not shrunk down, i.e. they would have to be at the same resolution.

Comment: You could however incrementally scale the thumbnail up, then do a cross correlation, and find where the maximum correlation is.

Comment: @user1443118 Yes, that was my thought :)

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need something more than javascript for this. I would look into the image processing with python. Possibly helpful links:

[scikits-image](http://scikits-image.org/)

[PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/)

[Image Comparison Algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1819124/image-comparison-algorithm)

[Machine Learning](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/)

Answer (score 0):

It probably matters a lot whether the downsizing was done by averaging or nearest pixel.  If the downsizing was done by nearest pixel, you can look for pixel value matches to correspond pixels in the original image with pixels in the downsized/cropped image.  Unless the images were stored in some lossless format, you'll have to make the match quite fuzzy, but if you can identify likely matches, the scale and position of the crop is immediately available.

If there was some averaging in the scaling, or too much loss in the image compression, you might do best by gaussian blurring both images and trying to match based on local features of the blurred images, for example the x,y of local minima or maxima of primary colors.  Again, the match
will have to be fuzzy.